# Unable to get rake task to add separate items into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rake-task, rakefile

I'm using nokogiri to scrape and add information to my db and I ran into some trouble creating a rake task to add separate items into the database. My Initial code was a jumble of randomness so I've recreated the error using arrays instead. Here is my rake file.

```
namespace :test_array do
desc "Send Array To DB"
task send_db: :environment do

info_1 = []
info_2 = []
info_3 = []
info_4 = []

    10.times do 
        info_1 << "test_1"
        info_2 << "test_2"
        info_3 << "test_3"
        info_4 << "test_4"
    end

    info_1.each do |x|
    test_1 = TestDb.new(test_1: x)
    test_1.save
    end

    info_2.each do |x|
    test_2 = TestDb.new(test_2: x)
    test_2.save
    end

    info_3.each do |x|
    test_3 = TestDb.new(test_3: x)
    test_3.save
    end

    info_3.each do |x|
    test_3 = TestDb.new(test_3: x)
    test_3.save
    end
  end
 end
```

And this is the console output

```
[#<TestDb id: 1, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 2, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 3, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 4, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 5, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 6, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 7, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 8, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 9, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, #<TestDb id: 10, test_1: "test_1", test_2: nil, test_3: nil, test_4: nil, created_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08", updated_at: "2014-08-26 02:22:08">, ...]>
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing but only the first loop adds info to the db and the rest seem to be ignored. I've tried running seperate rake tasks but that did not work, i'm guessing its a problem with my use of the .each method but i'm not sure how to fix. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this for now, it works but not sure if it's the best fit.

```
info_1.zip(info_2, info_3, info_4).each do |one, two, three, four|      
  TestDb.create(test_1: one, test_2: two, test_3: three, test_4: four)   
end
```